# Where to get info about deprecated options of OpenSSL RSAUTIL of Mojave?

Tags: osx, openssl, ssl

It seems that on macOS since Mojave (OSX 10.14.3), the `-ssl` option had been deprecated from RSA Utils (`rsautl` command) on it's default OpenSSL.

```sh
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.3
BuildVersion:   18D42
$ 
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

Where can I get these update releases info? I googled the net but couldn't find them...

---

If I try to use `-ssl` option then it returns the help as an error. But the `-ssl` option is still there.

```sh
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey id_rsa.pub.pkcs8 -ssl -in test.txt -out test.txt.enc
Usage: rsautl [options]
-in file        input file
-out file       output file
-inkey file     input key
-keyform arg    private key format - default PEM
-pubin          input is an RSA public
-certin         input is a certificate carrying an RSA public key
-ssl            use SSL v2 padding
-raw            use no padding
-pkcs           use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (default)
-oaep           use PKCS#1 OAEP
-sign           sign with private key
-verify         verify with public key
-encrypt        encrypt with public key
-decrypt        decrypt with private key
-hexdump        hex dump output
```

But in the manual, the `-ssl` option doesn't appear.

```sh
$ man openssl 
...
RSAUTL
     openssl rsautl [-asn1parse] [-certin] [-decrypt] [-encrypt] [-hexdump] [-in
     file] [-inkey file] [-keyform der | pem] [-oaep | -pkcs | -raw] [-out file]
     [-pubin] [-sign] [-verify]
...
```

I understand that since **SSL v2 is no longer good to use**, they deprecated the `-ssl` option.

But I need some kind of confirmation about this so to let my client know and change their protocol to send encrypted files.

I noticed that the `man` was updated today (my time, Jan 29, 2019, Tokyo).

```sh
$ man openssl | tail -1
BSD                      January 29, 2019                       BSD
```

So I thought that Apple just forgot to update the `-help`, but even in the [Mojave release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_mojave_10_14_3_release_notes) there was no info about it.

Where can I get info of these changes and/or report to update the `--help`?

Comment: The LibreSSL site is at https://www.libressl.org/ and it contains changelogs for all versions of LibreSSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found where. And seems that it wasn't the Apple's issue but LibreSSL's OpenBSD issue. I'm sorry Apple.

- [OpenBSD for LibreSSL](https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/) @ GitHub

In the latest commit's source code below, there still was the `-ssl` option.

- ["rsautl.c" (Line 321 / Commit 19a8bdc)](https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/blob/19a8bdc17a8fd67fe97e33f6d916108199cf376a/src/usr.bin/openssl/rsautl.c#L321)

I think this is the place to see the changes and report an issue.

Comment: This looks like a documentation bug.  The actual code that uses this option was removed in August 2017: https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/commit/286b2e2ae638bad06fdc2087d0bd938b0cb69375#diff-7cd392812913edd7bb9bc6354a2e43ef  I might file a bug report with a patch against the base OpenBSD tree.

Comment: This has been fixed now, but it'll take _some time_ before Apple updates its OpenSSL. Your bug report was ever so slightly earlier [than mine](https://marc.info/?t=154876038000004&r=1&w=2).

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you! Your report backed me up to tell my client that the documentation was wrong and all we have to do is wait!

Comment: ... and on my OpenBSD-current system, I can now see that `openssl` has indeed been fixed.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks announcing me. I confirmed the fix too! https://github.com/libressl-portable/openbsd/commit/033f890a3c613623c454d0a44ac14130c8764dba